# How to get the Taylor polynomial arctan with error?

Tags: calculus

We have to find Taylor polynomial $P_2(x)$ of $\arctan(x)$ of grade 2 from point $x = 0$

My answer was

If $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ then $f(0)=0$

And $f'(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ where $f'(0) = 1$

And $f''(x) = \frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ where $f''(0) = 0$

And $P_2(x) = x - \frac{1}{3}x^3 +  \frac{1}{5}x^5$

Then we have to use the Taylor theorem to show that $P_2(x) - \frac{1}{3}x^3 < \arctan(x) < P_2(x) + \frac{1}{12}x^3$
when $0 < x ≤ 1$

What should I do to get it? I know to calculate an error we use

$E_n(x)= \frac{f^{n+1}(s)}{(n+1)}(x-a)^{n+1}$

Where am I wrong exactly?

Comment: $P_2(x)$ usually denotes the second-order Taylor polynomial of a function $f$, namely, $f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2} f''(x_0) (x - x_0)^2$. If $x_0 = 0$ and $f$ is odd (as is the case here), all of the even-order terms are zero, so $P_2(x) = f'(0) x$.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is as follows. We know that if $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, then $f' = (1 + x^2)^{-1}$. Thus
$$ \arctan(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1 + t^2} dt + C$$
for some constant $C$. As $\arctan(0) = 0$, we even have that $C = 0$.

A Taylor expansion for $(1 + t^2)^{-1}$ is straightforward, as this is a geometric series
$$ \frac{1}{1 + t^2} = 1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \cdots$$
Thus the Taylor expansion for $\arctan(x)$ centered at $0$ is given by
$$ \arctan(x) = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7 + \cdots$$

For $x \geq 0$, this is an alternating series. For $0 \leq x < 1$, this is an alternating series with strictly decreasing (in magnitude) terms. Thus consecutive partial sums bound the actual value (as in the alternating series test for convergence).

Thus
$$ x - x^3/3 \leq \arctan(x) \leq x - x^3/3 + x^5/5.\tag{1}$$
This is stronger than the bound you were asked to show.

---

Nonetheless, you could go from this bound to the prescribed bound (if desired) by noting that for $0 \leq x < 1$, we have that $x^5/5 < x^4/4$, and further that $x^4/4 < x^3/4$, so that
$$\arctan(x) \leq x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 \leq x - x^3/3 + x^4/4 \leq x - x^3/3 + x^3/4$$,
which simplifies to
$$ \arctan(x) \leq x - x^3/12.$$
This is sort of silly, but this shows that the simpler bound in $(1)$ is stronger than the requested bound.

Comment: I have fixed the question as i've written it wrong. My apologies

Comment: @MathLove This answer still applies verbatim, except that the desired bound is now even weaker than the initial bound proved in my answer.